# I'm relatively new to java and I can't figure out keyboard presses for Pong

Tags: java, keyboard

- I'm in the process of making Pong for a class project and I can't figure out how to use keyboard inputs. I've looked at many guides online and nothing I do works. Any idea why it isn't registering any keyboard inputs? I'm fairly certain I have all the correct imports for this.

  ```
   package pong2;

   import java.awt.color.*;
   import javax.swing.JFrame;
   import java.awt.Canvas;
   import java.awt.Color;
   import java.awt.Graphics;
   import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
   import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
   import java.util.logging.Level;
   import java.util.logging.Logger;



   public class graphic extends Canvas implements KeyListener 
   {
           int y1 = 450;
           int y2 = 450;

           public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
           {
  ```
- JFrame

  ```
                       JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pong");
                       Canvas canvas = new graphic();
                       canvas.setSize(1920,1080);
                       frame.add(canvas);
                       frame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                       frame.pack();
                       frame.setVisible(true);
                       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                       frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() );

                       frame.repaint();

           }
  ```
- Key Listener

  ```
           @Override
           public void  keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
       {
               //System.out.println("Key Typed");
       }
           @Override
           public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
       {
               if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN); 
               {
                   //System.out.println("Key Pressed " + e.getKeyCode());
                   y2 = y2 - 10;
                   repaint();

               }       

               if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP);
               {
                   y2 = y2 + 10;
                   repaint();
               }
       }
           @Override

            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
        {
                   //System.out.println("Key Released");
        }
  ```
- Graphics for pong board

  ```
           public void paint(Graphics g) 
       {
               super.paint(g);

               //Background
               g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
               g.fillRect(0,0,1920,1080);

               //Goals
               g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
               g.fillRect(0,0,50,1080);
               g.fillRect(1870,0,50,1080);

               //Paddles
               g.fillRect(120,y1,20,150);
               g.fillRect(1790,y2,20,150);

               //Ball
               g.fillRect(950,525,20,20);
       }


   }
  ```

Comment: You've commented out the line where you were creating your key listener.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `graphic` class extends `Canvas` and implements `KeyListener` and you have your `Canvas` reference pointing to `graphic` object i-e `Canvas canvas = new graphic();`

Therefore you have to register `canvas` to listen for keyboard inputs.

Change `frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener())`

to

`frame.addKeyListener((KeyListener) canvas);`

or

`frame.addKeyListener((graphic) canvas);`